# How to do box plot using multiple monthly raster dataset?

Tags: r, raster, boxplot

How to do box plot using multiple monthly raster dataset and arrange it monthly by including all values of monthly dataset in each box?

I wish to do boxplot on multiple set of raster. These raster are of different months, so values vary widely. Also wish to rename (month-wise arrangement) and rearrange it monthly.
The below plot takes value from each raster but it does not expand, so interpretation is very difficult.
I had tried this code using desired library:

```
   setwd("H:/cc_fire/dataset/future_data/HadGEM3/test")
   v1 <- list.files(path = "H:/cc_fire/dataset/future_data/HadGEM3/test", pattern='.tif$', all.files=TRUE,       full.names=FALSE)
   s2data = stack(v1)
   boxplot(s2data)
```

[dataset used in this study](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oAwRasjXydnahTRsvHBAscdZ0TeYA7hQ?usp=share_link)

[image: This is the Output I am getting]

How to expand and include the minimum and maximum value of each month in the box plot, so that it include all values of each month of raster files which will make it more interpret able.